# 'getaddrinfo': identifier not found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, winsock2

I am getting started with WinSock 2 Programming on Windows 7 using C++ in Visual Studio 2017.  I am trying to get the winsock client example code here up and running: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx

I had to remove the windows.h inclusion in order to remove a whole bunch of errors, but there are 2 that I can't get rid of (related to each other).  When I try to build, I get the following error messages:
`C3861   freeaddrinfo': identifier not found
 C3861   getaddrinfo': identifier not found`

The frustrating thing is that visual studio seems to be able to resolve these references.  From the code, I can right-click->go to definition without any issues for both errors.  I am linking to ws2_32.lib so that isn't the problem either.  I've come across other instances of this problem on Windows XP or earlier in my searching, such as this one [GetAddrInfo identifier not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429384/getaddrinfo-identifier-not-found).  But I'm on Windows 7, so OS compatibility shouldn't be the issue.  I also tried including ws2tcpip.h and wspiapi.h, but that didn't help.

Here's all of my code for completeness' sake:

```
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <wspiapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

And my stdafx.h file:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.lib")


// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Put the include of `windows.h` back and fix the other error(s) - this is the root of your problems.  Also `#include "stdafx.h"` __MUST__ be the 1st include in any cpp/c file if you include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your headers are in the wrong order. `#include "stdafx.h"` should always be the first header include for a .c or .cpp file. (when using precompiled headedrs).

This is what's needed for stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <ws2tcpip.h>   // includes <winsock2.h> implicitly which in turn includes <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

This what's needed at the top of your main source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
...
```

Comment: It's the default Visual Studio project configuration.